# Rudder plugins compilation

Tags: configuration-management, rudder

I need to get rudder plugins, I git cloned it but I need to compile it on another machine which does not have access to the internet. I folllowed the instructions to compile the plugin in rudder-plugin directory,but it fails trying to download rudder-parent-5.0.0.pom. I downloaded it from another machine, scp it on the machine that can compile the code, but it still need to download the file. Do you have any instruction or a bundle like, to compile with all file needed (make/ar/maven/java8 jdk tools are already Installed on compilation machine) ?

Thank you for your help
Luc

Answer (score 2):

Compiling plugins on a machine without an internet connection, espicially without some fluency with maven build tool and local repository, can be hard. Maven is doing a lot of verification/download, which can be tedious to do by hand. 
So we recomand to build plugins on a connected machine, and then only deploy the resulting binary.

That being said, if you really, really want to try, the most likely solution is to first build a first time on the connected machine (or at least run a `mvn dependency:resolve` in the plugin directory after having done a `make generate-all-pom` in the plugins root directory). Then, `rsync` or  `tar` the `.m2/repository` directory (which is the place of maven local cache for downloaded jars), and transfert/extract it to the machine where the compilation will be done.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Is the rudder-plug-in compilationis Linux distrib dependant  ? Meaning if I compile it from another machine which is under redhat os and get the rpkg, this package can be Installed on the rudder master server which is under Debian ? Thank you for your reply and help

Comment: rudder plugins only depend of rudder versions, not the target os. So yes, you can compile on redhat, get the rpkg, and use it for a rudder installed on debian